# Integration and Plugin folders missing in cypress

Tags: plugins, cypress, integration

I have generated cypress folder..In that i could see only support and fixture folders. Integration and plugin folders are missing...pls help to resolve

Answer (score 3):

Apparently both the **Integration** folder and **Plugins** file/folder are deprecated, no longer created at install/setup. I encountered this myself, following what I now believe is an out-of-date tutorial.

Although, it is difficult to interpret the documentation:

- This Cypress documentation link seems to be the [current Configuration, Folders / Files](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Folders-Files). No `pluginsFile` and no `integrationFolder`.
- This Cypress documentation link is the [Legacy Configuration, Folders / Files](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/legacy-configuration#Folders-Files). It includes both the `pluginsFile` (and folder) and, the `integrationFolder`.

Answer (score 0):

The plugins file is no longer supported after Cypress version 10.0.0.
You should use config.js or config.ts

Comment: This seems to be 1/2 an answer, Substantiated here: [pluginsFile option was removed](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog#10-0-0:~:text=pluginsFile%20option%20was%20removed).